# How to use compile ES6 (react) components and foundation sass with npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, zurb-foundation

I followed [this tutorial](http://andrewhfarmer.com/build-your-own-starter/#0-intro) to setup a react project and I thought I nailed it. After installing everything works as it should.

But I have to create a website that uses foundation as a front-end lib. The tutorial I linked above runs server.js when I run `npm start` but foundation-cli uses the same command for compiling all foundation sass code to css.

At the moment when I run `npm start` it only runs react and not foundation. How can I run foundation too? can I make it so that it'll automatically run both?

Comment: Try out npm:concurrently, a useful package.

Comment: Never used Foundation myself, but I would say you should compile all your sass with Webpack since you are already using it...

Comment: @AluanHaddad That could solve the problem if I just knew what to run with it. Since both packages use the same command I don't know which two command I should run with concurrently.

Comment: @errata foundation-cli comes with build-it compiler that compiles scss to the correct folder at once. I guess that can be done with webpack too, but I couldn't find instructions how to do that kind of config for the webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using Webpack, I would suggest you to use one of the loaders for it and compile your CSS with it. [This one](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) seems like it can do that for you.

This is not tested, but I assume you can add it to your Webpack config like this:

```
// be sure to install it with
// npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    './main.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};
```